# Can't seem to find a solution for this error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Here is the error:

syntax error, unexpected token "=>", expecting ")"

And here is my code:

```
{{Form::open (array ('url' => 'logincheck'))}}

    <p> {{Form::text ('username', string ('placeholder'=>'Username','maxlength'=>30))}} </p>

    <p> {{Form::password ('password', string('placeholder'=>'Password','maxlength'=>30))}} </p>

    <p> {{Form::submit ('Submit')}} </p>

{{Form::close ()}}
```

Comment: The official documentation is here https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Answer (score 2):

Change the `string(`... to `array(`...

I recommend you use the short array syntax like that:

```php
{{ Form::text('username', ['placeholder' => 'Username', 'maxlength' => 30]) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature is `public function text($name, $value = null, $options = [])`
So to pass your options, you need to use an array.

```
{{ Form::open (array ('url' => 'logincheck')) }}
    

    <p> {{ Form::text ('username', '',['placeholder'=>'Username','maxlength'=>30]) }} </p>

    <p> {{ Form::password ('password', '', ['placeholder'=>'Password','maxlength'=>30]) }} </p>

    <p> {{ Form::submit ('Submit') }} </p>

{{ Form::close ()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try refining your input fields like so:

```php
{{ Form::text('username', null, array('placeholder' => 'Username','maxlength' => 30 )) }}

{{ Form::password('password', null, array('placeholder' => 'Password','maxlength' => 30 )) }}
```

BTW, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: It is still supported by laravel Collective.

Comment: Huh! Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the `string` with `array`
Try this code

```
{{Form::open (array ('url' => 'logincheck'))}}

    <p> {{Form::text ('username', array('placeholder'=>'Username','maxlength'=>30))}} </p>

    <p> {{Form::password ('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password','maxlength'=>30))}} </p>

    <p> {{Form::submit ('Submit')}} </p>

{{Form::close ()}}
```